Log-rank test statistic for multi-way splitting in survival trees
In survival trees, the log-rank test statistic is most often used for split selection. This involves selecting the binary split that produces the largest value of the log-rank test statistic.
This assumes that log-rank test statistic values with equal group sizes are comparable to those with unequal group sizes, because the resulting child nodes differ in size to different degrees depending on where the current candidate split point is.
Now I'm interested in performing multi-way splitting, where each node is split into more than two child nodes. Here, I want to use the test statistic of the log-rank test for more than two groups to choose the split points of the multi-way split so that the child nodes differ most strongly in their survival.
But I'm not sure this approach would be valid. This is because I don't know if the comparability of log-rank test statistic values for different relative group sizes (with the same total number of observations) also holds for the log-rank test for more than two groups. The latter, however, would be necessary to choose the multi-way splits without favoring strongly balanced or strongly unbalanced divisions.
I would appreciate any guesses or insights on this.

How are you proposing to vary the 2+ cutoffs of a predictor needed to get a 3+ way split at a node? The log-rank test certainly works with multiple groups, but it only determines that there is some difference among the groups, not that you have found the best distinction among all 3+ groups.

@EdM I will choose the best 3+ way split from several randomly generated candidates. The trees will be used in a random forest variant, so it is not critical to find the optimal 3+ way split among all possible 3+ way splits. Hmm, I thought that the test statistic would get larger if all 3+ groups were strongly different, but I see that it will also be large if only a subset of the groups are strongly different from each other. Perhaps an alternative would be to perform the two-sample log rank test between all pairs of groups, and then take the minimum from that as a split criterion.
